# Is "I really liked its theme" the only acceptable alternative to "I also very much liked its theme" in this exam question?

Tags: clauses, exam-questions

> I really enjoyed the way the fashion show was executed and **I also very much liked its theme**.
>
> 1. Its theme conveyed.
> 2. I really liked its theme.
> 3. No improvement.

It's my exam question and provisional answer key suggests option 2. But I can't understand what's wrong with 1&3.

Answer (score 1):

From you original sentence

> I really enjoyed the way the fashion show was executed and **I also very much liked its theme**.

The first choice

> I really enjoyed the way the fashion show was executed and **its theme conveyed**.

is ungrammatical, however

> I really enjoyed the way the fashion show was executed and **what** its theme 
>   conveyed.

is possible.

> I really enjoyed the way the fashion show was executed and **I really liked its theme**.

Is obvious as it conveys exactly the same idea of the original sentence.